# Struts 2 and Freemarker Theme Roller

Tags: struts2, themes, freemarker

I Have a struts.xml with

`<constant name="struts.ui.theme" value="black" />
<constant name="struts.ui.templateDir" value="template" />`

---

However if i change 
`<constant name="struts.ui.theme" value="black" />` to
`<constant name="struts.ui.theme" value="white" />` i'm getting white theme
i want to know how to change this setting in form onchange event of select box..?

I have worked around but i'm not able to get this..
If you want any more clarification i'll give it please let me know before you close

Comment: you want to change theme at run time?

Comment: yes.. user can select a theme from selectbox and it should change in run time.. it's similar to jquery theme roller.

Comment: Jquery theme roller is css based and do it in DOM but Struts2 theme is something different and need to use different freemarker tempelate

Comment: you need to reload the page when you select a new theme since selecting a new theme means regenerating HTML form free maker template.

Comment: k.. so where should i change from black to white..? page reload is not issue i'm not getting how to change it..

Comment: since you can not change in property file at run time nor in XML but Struts2 provides a way to set theme per page level like `<s:set name="theme" value="'simple'" scope="page" />` al you need to set the value of theme at page load.

Comment: for Static value it's working fine i want to know the dynamic one like `<s:set name="theme" value="%{myTheme}" scope="page" />` i got this from [Here](https://cwiki.apache.org/WW/can-i-change-theme-on-a-per-page-basis.html) but i'm confused where to change this myTheme

Comment: put the above code in your page header section and based on the changed in value you can set this theme property at run time/page load